# Why is my unity animation disappearing for one frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a 4 frame 2d fire animation. The fire animation is on top of a floor tile. For 3 frames, it works fine, but on one of the frames, it disappears behind the floor tile. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you given it a Sorting Layer that's in front of the floor tile sorting layer?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Wait I figured it out thank you so much.

Comment: Great.  I've added an answer to the question.  If you accept that answer, it might help other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the animated fire sprite to a Sorting Layer that is in front of the floor tile and any other background sprites.

You can create and assign sorting layers by following this documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html